# Pop object from array if instance variable is true

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, object

I need to pop an object from an array if its instance variable is `true`. For example:

```
a = Object.new
b = Object.new
c = Object.new

a.status = false
b.status = true
c.status = false

array << a
array << b
array << c

result = array.pop_if {|x| x.instance_variable_get == true}
result #=> b
```

The above is an example and I know that it would not work in this way. But I cannot find the right approach.

Comment: `instance_variable_get` needs an argument. What is the name of the instance variable you are mentioning?

Comment: Yes, you do have nice hair. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you keep it simple:

```
def remove_last_instance(arr, ivar, val)
  ivar = ivar.to_sym
  i = arr.rindex { |e| e.instance_variable_get(ivar) == val }
  i && arr.delete_at(i)
end

a = Object.new
  #=> #<Object:0x007fadea06a1b8> 
b = Object.new
  #=> #<Object:0x007fadea04a4f8> 
c = Object.new
  #=> #<Object:0x007fadea023010> 

a.instance_variable_set(:@status, false)
b.instance_variable_set(:@status, true)
c.instance_variable_set(:@status, false)

arr = [a,b,c]
  #=> [#<Object:0x007fadeb012bd8 @status=false>,
  #    #<Object:0x007fadea818cc0 @status=true>,
  #    #<Object:0x007fadea809900 @status=false>] 

remove_last_instance(arr, :@status, true)
  #=> #<Object:0x007fadea04a4f8 @status=true> 
arr
  #=> [#<Object:0x007fadea06a1b8 @status=false>,
  #    #<Object:0x007fadea023010 @status=false>]
```

which you could alternatively invoke:

```
remove_last_instance(arr, "@status", false)
```

Lastly,

```
remove_last_instance(arr, "@status", 'cat')
  #=> nil
remove_last_instance(arr, "@dog", true)
  #=> nil
```

I see no reason for this to be an instance method of `Array` and since [Array#pop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pop) pertains only to the last element of an array, I don't think `"pop"` should be part of the method's name.

Answer (score 1):

You want Ruby's [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#class-OpenStruct-label-Examples-3A) class for this. Here is a thought :

```
require 'ostruct'

a = OpenStruct.new
b = OpenStruct.new
c = OpenStruct.new

a.status = false
b.status = true
c.status = false

array = []
array << a
array << b
array << c
array.delete_if { |o| o.status }

p array # [#<OpenStruct status=false>, #<OpenStruct status=false>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Monkey patch `Array` class:

```
class Array
  def pop_if(&block)
    return enum_for(:pop_if) unless block_given?
    last_index = rindex(&block)
    delete_at last_index if last_index
  end
end
```

Test:

```
ary = (1..4).to_a
ary.pop_if(&:odd?)  #=> 3
ary  #=> [1, 2, 4]
ary.pop_if(&:odd?)  #=> 1
ary  #=> [2, 4]
ary.pop_if(&:odd?)  #=> nil
ary  #=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: @Borsunho `delete_if` deletes all items if the block returns truthy value, not just delete the first one.

Comment: Right, I missed the `return`, sorry.

Comment: @Borsunho Updated the implementation to immediately return the last item that meets the condition, without reversing the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way this can be done, `pop_if` shown below will `pop` only one element to be consistent with `Array#pop`, the element picked will be the one for which given block returns `true`, and element will be picked from the end of array - hence `rindex` has been used to find such element

```
a = Object.new
b = Object.new
c = Object.new

a.instance_variable_set(:@status, false)
b.instance_variable_set(:@status, true)
c.instance_variable_set(:@status, false)

array = []
array << a
array << b
array << c

class Array
    def pop_if
       return enum_for(:pop_if) if not block_given?
       delete_at(self.rindex{ |x| yield x })
    end
end

# block given
result = array.pop_if {|x| x.instance_variable_get(:@status) == true}
p result  # pops "b"

# if block not given in pop_if, can execute enumerator later
pop_enum = array.pop_if
p pop_enum.each { |x| x.instance_variable_get(:@status) == false } # pops "c"
```

Non monkey-patch version will look like below:

```
def pop_if(array, &block)
    array.delete_at(array.rindex {|x| yield x} )
end
```